# WinDivert Issue

Tags: c++, c, network-programming

I Have an issue with [WinDivert](http://reqrypt.org/windivert.html).  DivertSend does not work,  GetLastError() return 1237 ?

I have a another question. I want to divert traffic based on an IP list, I have a CSV file with more than 20000 records, each record contain an IP range, the problem is I can just call DivertOpen with only 500 record of my CSV file as a filter string. if I call DivertOpen with more than 500 record as filter I got "filter syntax error". How can i fix this issue.
Thanks

Comment: One question at a time. :) And be more specific with your first question. Like show your code.

Comment: Sorry for my bad. first question fixed i could not use DivertSend because of ESET Endpoint security, now  it is fixed.

Comment: Lulyon  can you please help me about second question?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the second question. Someone else will offer the help.

Answer (score 1):

WinDivert is not designed to handle long/complicated filter strings (such as a list of 20,000 IP addresses).  This is briefly mentioned in the [WinDivert documentation](http://reqrypt.org/windivert-doc.html#filter_usage): namely, the filter string should ideally be both *selective* and *short*, and the more shorter/selective the better.

For your kind of application, where a short string is not possible, you are better off capturing *all* network traffic (e.g. with a call to `DivertOpen("true", ...)`) and doing the filtering in the user-mode application using some efficient method (such as binary search).  Simply re-inject the packets that do not match.

PS: Thanks for the report of the 1237 error issue.

Comment: Thanks Dear Basil. I want to report another issue with DivertSend. sometimes it return 1233 error. do you have any idea about that?

Comment: 1233 = ERROR_PROTOCOL_UNREACHABLE. Not sure what would cause this. Perhaps trying to inject a packet with an invalid ip.Version or ip.Protocol value?

Comment: I Just Run passthrue example.

Comment: Basil there is another issue, I have "Keiro VPN Client" on my machine, I start Kerio and start netdump example, i get error "Junk packet".

Comment: This and the other issue (1233 error) might be related.  I will investigate.